# Node.js + Mongoose works locally, but not on Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

Here's my node.js file I'm running on Heroku. It works perfectly locally, but when I push it to Heroku, the database collection isn't created and no errors are thrown. Ultimately I'm just trying to get it to actually creating the connection while it's running on Heroku. Thanks.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    db_url = process.env.MONGOHQ_URL || "mongodb://john:<mypasswordwashere>@staff.mongohq.com:10053/app3305538",
    db = mongoose.connect(db_url),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Mongoose DB Test
var MsgSchema = new Schema({
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    message: String
});
var MsgModel = db.model("messages", MsgSchema);
var Msg = new MsgModel();
Msg.message = "blurgh";
Msg.save();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you specify node version in heroku?

please refer this. ( I also confused same issue. but resolved.)
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-versions

Answer (score 2):

Your call to `.save()` takes a callback function. Try adding a debug message in there and see if it shows any information about why its failing, like this:

```
Msg.save(function(err){
  if(err){ 
    console.log("Error:", err);
  }else{
    console.log("success");
  }
})
```

Then you should be able to see the result in the heroku logs.

Comment: I added the console messages but neither of them are being called in the Heroku logs.

Comment: Add debug messages to figure out which line of code your script is hanging on. Most likely it's mongoose.connect, and its probably something to do with MONGOHQ_URL. try setting the environment variable locally and connecting to the mongohq instance with mongoose locally instead of from heroku.

Comment: can you double-check + post what version of nodejs (and mongodb driver version) is being used by the heroku app?

Answer (score 0):

Another possible source of confusion is if you are sourcing both MongoLab and MongoHQ, then the default connection string provided in the Heroku [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#using-mongodb) will break your DB session:

```
var mongoUri = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || process.env.MONGOHQ_URL || 'mongodb://localhost/mydb';
```

i.e.: if you are using MongoHQ only with both installed, you should throw away the `process.env.MONGOLAB_URI`