# Deploying Meteor and MongoDB to Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, meteor

I am attempting to deploy my project to Heroku following a particular guide (http://bytesofpi.com/post/20898722298/pushing-your-meteor-project-to-heroku)

One of the steps states that

```
var mongo_url = process.env.MONGOHQ_URL;
```

Needs to replace "MONGO_URL" in server/server.js.

The problem is I can't find that variable at all, the only mention of that variable is in the following code

```
    // check for a valid MongoDB URL right away
    if (!process.env.MONGO_URL)
         throw new Error("MONGO_URL must be set in environment");
```

Does anybody have any experience with this, or know where to find "MONGO_URL in order to change it?

Comment: That's an environmental variable like process.env.PORT and process.env.HOST that the Heroku environment makes available to the application. So just change it as required in the if statement and it should work. Also check a related question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730567/node-js-mongoose-works-locally-but-not-on-heroku

Answer (score 14):

I would suggest that instead of using the article you mentioned as a guide that you do the following:

Use Meteorite to build and run your local Meteor projects:

```
https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite
```

Instructions are on that page.

Then use this buildpack:

```
https://github.com/oortcloud/heroku-buildpack-meteorite
```

Again, the README has how to create your app on Heroku (a one-liner)

The NOTE at the bottom of this README means that you need to verify your Heroku Account with a payment card so that you can add the mongohq:free add-on to your app. Once verified run:

```
heroku addons:add mongohq:sandbox
```

To add the db on Heroku.

Then the other step is to set the ROOT_URL for you app, type this inside your local app directory once the app is committed (only the first time):

```
heroku config:set ROOT_URL=<<domain of your app>>
```

Unless you are using a custom name <> will be something like

```
http://appname.herokuapp.com
```

If you then run:

```
heroku config
```

you will see that MONGOHQ_URL has been set alongside BUILDPACK_URL and ROOT_URL.

Comment: Thanks iacii for keeping the answer up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Oortcloud buildpack is the best Heroku buildpack I've used.

That being said, Heroku is a dead end, because it doesn't support session affinity.  At least, you might be able to get your app up and running on Heroku, but you won't ever be able to scale it with multiple dynos, unless the Heroku folks decide to replace all their load balancers.  FYI.  Dead end.

CloudBees looks like it may be the better Meteor hosting platform...
https://github.com/CloudBees-community/meteor-clickstart

Comment: Heroku now supports session affinity. https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2015/4/28/introducing_session_affinity

Answer (score 0):

I browsed to this title many times trying to find an up-to-date solution for deploying my local Meteor Mongo db to Heroku. So I am posting this answer here for anyone who does the same, although the question is really about setting the MONGO_URL.

Here is an updated solution (Meteor 1.3.2.4) for pushing local Meteor Mongo database to Heroku with (free) mLabs. My app did not use meteorite, and it used the "horse" buildpack.

**1. make a dump of your local mongo db**

In terminal (NOT mongo shell) in your app folder,

```
mongodump --port=3001 -o ../dump
```

**2. move the db files out of the "dump/your-db-name" up into "dump"**

In my local meteor instance, the /dump folder was placed in the folder above my app, so "dump" was in the same directory as my app's folder. "dump" contained a folder named after my database ("dump/my-database-name/"). This causes the next script to fail with a mongorestore error "don't know what do do with 'my-database-name'".  To prevent the error, move all of the files in the folder "my-database-name" up into "dump", then delete the "my-database-name" folder.

By default, your database name is "meteor", so if you haven't changed it, look for "dump/meteor/".

**3. in mLabs, if you haven't done so, create a user with admin privileges.** For me, the default user assigned at setup did not work.

**4. Push your dumped database to mLabs for your Heroku app.** This assumes you have added the mLabs plugin in your Heroku app, and have set the "MONGO_URL" in your Heroku app config. If these aren't done, they must be done first.

In terminal (not the mongo shell), change from your app's directory to the directory that holds the "dump" directory. In my case, it was just "cd ../".

Get your default "import" script by going to the mLabs plugin for your Heroku app, and clicking the "Tools" tab.  This script did not work for me, but it may work for you. If it doesn't, paste this script, with your variables replacing bracketed variables (replace the brackets, also).

```
mongorestore -h [your mLabs value]  -d [your mLabs default user name] -u [your mLabs created user name] -p [your mLabs created user's password]
```

After the script runs, you should be able to refresh your mLabs "Collections" tab and see your pushed data.

Good luck :)  I hope this helps someone!